# MVC: Value in dropdown menu doesn't set to selected value - remains 0

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, drop-down-menu, thymeleaf

This is a spring Boot application that uses thymeleaf template manager. It has a simple **form with dropdown menu**. Options are populated from database, both their names (or ids) can be displayed correctly on form but **after selecting option and submiting form value of given selected variable remains 0**.

While I get the correct value of variable `content`, `categoryId` always has value 0 after submit (or null if I change it's type from int to Integer).

I'm guessing that model isn't correctly "linked" to `jokeForm` but I don't know how to link it correctly. I was following [example 1](https://o7planning.org/en/11659/thymeleaf-form-select-option-example#a14065280). I hope someone can eassily spot the problem just by quickly looking at my code. Code breakes in method `submitForm()`.

HTML form:

```html
        <html>
        <body>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/new}" th:object="${jokeForm}" method="post"> 
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Content:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('content')}" th:errors="*{content}">Content Error</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Category:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="categoryId" th:field="*{categoryId}">
                         <option  value="0" th:each="category : ${categories}"
                            th:value="${category.id}"
                            th:utext="${category.name}"/>
                         <!-- <option th:each="category : *{categories}"
                            th:value="*{category.id}"
                            th:utext="*{category.name}"/> -->
                         </select>
                    </td>
                    <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('categoryId')}" th:errors="*{categoryId}">category Error</td>
                </tr>
               <tr> 
                    <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```java
    @GetMapping("/new")
    public String showForm( Model model) {
       DEBUG("showForm");
       JokeForm form = new JokeForm();
       categories = categoryRepository.findAll();


       DEBUG(categories.get(0).toString());
       DEBUG(categories.get(1).toString());

       //form.setCategories(categories); //not working
       model.addAttribute("jokeForm", form);          
       model.addAttribute("categories",categories);

       return "form";
    }


    @PostMapping("/new")
    @ResponseBody
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute JokeForm jokeForm) {
        DEBUG("submitForm");
        //String content = jokeForm.getContent();
        DEBUG(jokeForm.getContent());
        DEBUG(jokeForm.getCategoryId().toString());


        Joke j = new Joke();
        j.setContent(jokeForm.getContent());
        //j.setCategoryId(jokeForm.getCategoryId());

        //DEBUG(Integer.toString(jokeForm.getCategoryId()));
//CAUSES ERROR value of CategoryId is Integer -> null       System.out.println(Integer.toString(jokeForm.getCategoryId())); 
//PRODUCES ERROR value of CategorId is int (because no category matches)        j.setCategory(categoryRepository.findById(jokeForm.getCategoryId().intValue()).get(0));

jokeRepository.save(j); //save

        return "Saved";
    }
```

JokeForm

```java
        public class JokeForm {


    @NotEmpty(message = "content may not be empty")
    private String content;

    @NotEmpty(message = "category may not be empty") 
    private int categoryId; //int-> 0, Integer -> null

        /*
    @NotEmpty(message = "category may not be empty") 
    private Category category;

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    private List<Category> categories;
    public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    } */

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Integer getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategory(Integer categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `value="0"` for all options.

`<select>` should be:

```
<select th:field="*{categoryId}">
   <option th:each="category : ${categories}"
      th:value="${category.id}"
      th:utext="${category.name}"/>
      <!-- <option th:each="category : *{categories}"
         th:value="*{category.id}"
         th:utext="*{category.name}"/> -->
</select>
```

Edit:
and add (setter) `setCategoryId()` in JokeForm class

Comment: Good guess, sadly that's not it, or at least isn't the only thing. And if I set this value to "2" it still remains 0.

Comment: The problem seems to be with `jokeForm.categoryId`, it's value doesn't set even with `input type= text`. I can't see how it is much different from `content`

Comment: There was no method  `setCategoryId()`, fml.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not find out at first